# PHP/mysqli , how to know about newly inserted ID

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a simple table , contains a primary key which has an Auto Increment index.

When I do insertion with `mysqli` , is there any chance to know the last inserted value of the Auto Increment column ?

Note:

There might be multiple people trying to insert simultaneously

Comment: wont [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) work?

Comment: Is [mysqli_insert_id  function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) doesn't work???

Comment: Note that the simultaneous thing is covered with `mysqli_insert_id()` because it returns the last inserted id for the current session.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use: [`mysqli_insert_id($con)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the insert_id value (not a method call) from the database object :)

```
$id = $db->insert_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Correction to last post, procedural style takes a parameter "$link", where $link is the identifier returned by mysqli_connect() or mysqli_init():

`$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);`

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php - mysql_insert_id()

Answer (score 1):

```
   $last_id = $link->insert_id;
```

Where `$link` is MySQLi resource.

Or:

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id();
```